# Java method generic

Tags: java, generics, java-11

I have the following code:

```
private Set<? extends DecisionGroupDto> parentGroups = new HashSet<>();

public DecisionDto(Decision decision) {
    super(decision);
    if (decision != null) {
        Set<? extends DecisionGroup> parentGroups = decision.getParentGroups();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(parentGroups)) {
            for (DecisionGroup parentGroup : parentGroups) {
                this.parentGroups.add(new DecisionGroupDto(parentGroup));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

right now the following line:

```
this.parentGroups.add(new DecisionGroupDto(parentGroup));
```

fails with the following error:

```
Required type: capture of ? extends DecisionGroupDto
Provided:DecisionGroupDto
```

How to allow `this.parentGroups` accept not only derived classes from `DecisionGroupDto` but also and `DecisionGroupDto` itself?

Comment: You would have to declare it as `Set<DecisionGroupDto>`. But that limits what you can assign to `parentGroups` (and perhaps you don't need that)

Comment: Why did you use `? extends` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use super instead of extends

```
private Set<? extends DecisionGroupDto> parentGroups = new HashSet<>();

public DecisionDto(Decision decision) {
    super(decision);
    if (decision != null) {
        Set<? super DecisionGroup> parentGroups = decision.getParentGroups();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(parentGroups)) {
            for (DecisionGroup parentGroup : parentGroups) {
                this.parentGroups.add(new DecisionGroupDto(parentGroup));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To specify the lower bounding class of a type wildcard, the super keyword is used. This keyword indicates that the type argument is a supertype of the bounding class.  Adding to such a list requires either elements of type DecisionGroup, any subtype of DecisionGroup or null (which is a member of every type).